# Troubleshooting ARD and making connections more reliable

Tags: remote-desktop, apple-remote-desktop

I use ARD to admin 6 computers, sometimes i can connect to 5 of the computers fine, but 1 of them will just not connect and i get an error like the below screenshot. I have got this computer to connect in the past but as of recently it never connects. Whats odd is that i can see all system info like current programme, OS, installed ram etc, but just cant get the control connection to establish.

[image: screen shot of error when connecting via ARD]

All machines are connected to the same wired gigabit cat6 network, which consists of 3 switches linked back to a router. All the machines have mac to ip bindings so their IP address dosnt change.

Any ideas what could be done ?

My machines spec is as follows :

- 1) the dial out client machine : Macbook pro, 10.10.5, ARD latest
- 2) mac mini, 10.11.x (latest), ARD 3.9.3
- 3) mac mini, 10.10.x (latest), ARD 3.9.3
- 4) mac mini, 10.11.x (latest), ARD 3.9.3
- 5) mac mini, 10.12.x (latest), ARD 3.9.3
- 6) macbook pro, 10.12.x (latest), ARD 3.9.3

Not all of the machines are online at the moment so they wont be in the below screenshot. The machine im having issues with has the IP ending 103.

Please also see screenshot of sharing permissions for that computer.

[image: screenshot of ARD]

[image: screenshot of connection settings on the machine in question]

Comment: Screenshot?  What types of Macs are you attempting to admin?

Comment: @Allan apologies, missed the screenshot, please see updated question now containing it. Ive also added info about the machines in question.

Comment: There's a dashboard on ARD.  Can you post a shot of that?  Also, can you ping the Mac in question?

Comment: @Allan if i ping 192.168.1.43 i get : `PING 192.168.1.43 (192.168.1.43): 56 data bytes Request timeout for icmp_seq 0` i presume this is because the machine is now asleep, ill try again tomorrow when the user is back at their computer

Comment: Assuming that the IP address is correct, you have your answer.  You can't manage it with ARD if you can't reach (ping) it.    If it's asleep or disconnected, there's nothing that ARD can do.  If you notice, there's a greyed-out icon next to the computer name meaning it's "offline"

Comment: There is an option in ARD (forgive me, I can't remember where exactly) to Wake the target Mac. Does that not work? Assuming that it is not turned off or otherwise disconnected from the network you should be able to wake any Mac from ARD to which you have the appropriate permissions

Comment: @SteveChambers - You have to allow for waking via Network Activity in Energy Preferences for it to happen.  Apple "says" it will attempt to wake a Mac, but in my experience, it's failed more often than succeeded.  I had better luck ditching ARD and going with homegrown scripts.

Comment: Bizarre, It works every time for me, usually takes a minute but never a problem with the 4 systems I admin with it...

Comment: @Allan please see question updated with more specific info above, hopefully question can be re opened based upon this

Comment: @Allan wondered if you'd had a chance to review the editted question and the possibility of re opening it in light of the edits ?

Comment: The question has been reopened and is not on hold.

Comment: I suggest you prevent the macs from sleeping at all if it is essential to use ARD if the Wake on LAN does not work reliably. You can set the screen to turn off after a period of inactivity to save energy. You can read about Wake on LAN [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN). Depending on your network topology, which looks simple, Wake on LAN should work fine. Have you checked to make sure the port characteristics on the switch that the unreachable computer sits on is not blocking or discarding the magic packet? Connect the computer to another port or switch as a test.